# How do I setup Fmod to very basic functionality in a Win32 console application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fmod

I'm new to Visual Studio and would like to set up the very basic functionality of Fmod in a Win32 console application.

What I think the main problem is, is that I don't understand quite good how headers, additional libraries and dll files work.

Currently I have added "fmodex64_vc.lib" to additional dependencies. The following error occurs:

```
Error   1   error C3861: 'FSOUND_Init': identifier not found    c:\PATH\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\fmod\fmod\test.cpp    13
```

And I use the following code:

```
#include "include/fmod.h"
#include "include/fmod.hpp"
#include "include/fmod_errors.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Initalize the Fmod System at 44Khz and 32 channels
    if(FSOUND_Init(44100, 32, 0))
    {
        printf("FMOD Init OK\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("FMOD Init Failed!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fmodex64_vc.lib is an import library for FMODEx (version 4.xx.xx), FSOUND_Init is a function from FMOD (version 3.xx.xx) the two are not compatible. I'm guessing you have downloaded the latest FMODEx release, but are using example code from somewhere else (designed for FMOD3). I would recommend looking inside the FMODEx install directory and use the examples found within along with the fmodex.chm docs as a reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You have solved the problem partly. The other part was that I downloaded the 64 bit version and tried to implement it into a win32 application.